# Jedis does not support returning PendingMessagesSummary

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

When I start the spring app write with Java 11, show error like this:

```
[12:36:01:729] [ERROR] - com.dolphin.soa.post.common.mq.PendingMessageConsume.pendingMessage(PendingMessageConsume.java:36) - handle pending message with an error
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Jedis does not support returning PendingMessagesSummary.
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisStreamCommands.xPending(JedisStreamCommands.java:279) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.xPending(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:567) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.xPending(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:4758) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultStreamOperations.lambda$pending$11(DefaultStreamOperations.java:250) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultStreamOperations$$Lambda$1468/0x00000000640b3c40.doInRedis(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:223) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:190) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:97) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultStreamOperations.pending(DefaultStreamOperations.java:250) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.common.mq.PendingMessageConsume.handlePendingMessage(PendingMessageConsume.java:42) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.common.mq.PendingMessageConsume.pendingMessage(PendingMessageConsume.java:34) [classes!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
```

I have already upgrade the Jedis version to the newest 4.2.3, why still did not support the Redis pending command? I have already read the Jedis [issue](https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues/2274). They already added the pending support in the Jedis 3.6.0, why still tell me that did not support? This is the project Jedis dependencies look like:

```
➜  dolphin-post git:(master) ✗ ./gradlew :dolphin-post:dolphin-post-service:dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath|grep -v "(*)"|grep -C 10 "jedis"
     |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.19
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis -> 2.6.7
     |    |    |    \--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.6.4
     |    |    |         +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:2.6.4
     |    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.6.4
     |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32 -> 1.7.36
     |    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.19
     |    |    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32 -> 1.7.36
     |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.3.19
     |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32 -> 1.7.36
     |    |    +--- redis.clients:jedis:4.2.3 -> 3.7.1
     |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 1.7.36
     |    |    |    \--- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.10.0 -> 2.11.1
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis -> 2.6.3
     |    |    |    +--- org.springframework.session:spring-session-core:2.6.3
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.3.19
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop -> 2.6.7
     |    |    |    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.7
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test -> 2.6.7
     |    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.6.7
     |    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.6.7
```

this is my java code looks like:

```
void handlePendingMessage(){
        StreamOperations<String, String, String> streamOperations = this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForStream();
       PendingMessagesSummary pendingMessagesSummary = streamOperations.pending(consumer,groupName);
       Long totalPendingMessageCount = pendingMessagesSummary.getTotalPendingMessages();
       String groupName = pendingMessagesSummary.getGroupName();
        List<MapRecord<String, String, String>> retVal = streamOperations.read(Consumer.from(groupName, "my_consumer1"), StreamOffset.create(consumer, ReadOffset.from("0")));
        for (MapRecord<String, String, String> record : retVal ) {
            //streamOperations.acknowledge(groupName, record);
        }
    }
```

what should I do to make it support `PendingMessagesSummary`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using Jedis directly. You are using it through spring-data-redis.

Even though Jedis has added the support of PendingMessagesSummary, spring-data-redis has not included the support of Jedis. That is why you are getting the error.